# Java Scanner issue with a regex matching a space

Tags: java, regex, space

I want a space between words. I had tried using `Pattern.compile("a\\sb")` in Java but it fails for `a b`.

This is the code I used:

```
String str; 
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Enter String");  
str=sc.next(); 
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("a\\sb"); 
Matcher m = pat.matcher(str);    
if( m.find() ) { 
     System.out.println("Success"); 
} else { 
     System.out.println("Failed"); 
}
```

Comment: `"a\\sb"`.............

Comment: i had tried the same

Comment: @RaghavendraDillikar any error reports? Did you use Matcher class?

Comment: This pattern looks very good. Please give us a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) explaining your problem.

Comment: i think java is not accepting \\s for space

Comment: @RaghavendraDillikar m not much into java...but have a doubt...you are compiling..then you are using `.match` or something right?is the string exactly same as `a b`....is there a `space` before `a`

Comment: we can't tell unless you post the complete code.

Comment: String str;
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter String");
  str=sc.next();
                Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("a\\sb"); 
                 Matcher m = pat.matcher(str); 
    if( m.find() ) { 
         System.out.println("Success"); 
         }
         else
         {
          System.out.println("Failed");
         }

Comment: Well, the question is crystal clear after OP provided the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

So, try using it as

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[\r\n]+");
```

This way, we'll tokenize using line breaks.

Have a look at the [demo](https://ideone.com/ATrcvI).